# Как отключить информацию по клику на объект react-yandex-maps?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Я использую react-yandex-maps и хочу отключить запрос к Яндексу при клике на какой-нибудь объект на карте (см. скриншот).  Если я предоставляю apikey, то запросы идут, без ключа же запросы не идут и всплывающего окна нет. Мне надо использовать ключ, поэтому я хочу отключить такие запросы. Также при клике на существующий объект не срабатывает `onClick` карты.[image: пример информации при клике]